# How to calculate cumulative average

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to calculate cumulative average  of my data.

in my query i get sum value for every date now.But I am confused How to calculate calculate cumulative average.

my query

```
SELECT 
  u.id,
  (SUM(m.protein)),
  DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(u.create)) AS Cdate,
  goal.what,
  goal.value 
FROM
  `meal` AS m,
  `user_history` AS u 
LEFT JOIN goal 
    ON goal.what = 'Protein' 
    AND goal.user_id = 48 
WHERE u.meal_id = m.id 
  AND u.user_id = 48 
GROUP BY DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(u.create))
```

Here I get the sum value by `sum(m.protein)` but i want here cumulative average

Comment: Can we get some sample starting data and desired results, please?  Do you want cumulative per-day?  Do you want the average of the sum, or the average of the individual `protein` values?  You're mixing old and new style joins, which you shouldn't be doing (just use new-style, that is, the `JOIN` clause).  Your query won't be able to use parts of indices that include `create`, due to the use of functions - if you can define a range table your query may be more efficient.  Having columns not in the `GROUP BY`/an aggregate function can yield subtly wrong results, maybe you need to rollup first?

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @csum=0;
SELECT 
  u.id,
  (SUM(m.protein)) as sum1,
  (@csum := @csum + sum1) as CSUM,
  DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(u.create)) AS Cdate,
  goal.what,
  goal.value 
FROM
  `meal` AS m,
  `user_history` AS u 
LEFT JOIN goal 
    ON goal.what = 'Protein' 
    AND goal.user_id = 48 
WHERE u.meal_id = m.id 
  AND u.user_id = 48 
GROUP BY DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(u.create))
```

Comment: Where is the average calculated?

Comment: is it works with mysql?
I am getting error Unknown column 'sum' in 'field list'

Comment: Yes it worked in mysql. Try with sum1 because sum is reserve word

Comment: @shree.pat18 `(@csum := @csum + sum1) as CSUM,`

Comment: @shree.pat18 you mean i have to add somthing like `avg(m.protein)`

Comment: @sadikhAsan Sum over count